# Replace DbContext in WebApplicationFactory for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to replace context in WebApplicationFactory. I have MyDbContext which I want to replace with SQLite context for testing.

The replace part works fine

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
  {
    // Remove the app's ApplicationDbContext registration.
    var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>));

    if (descriptor != null)
    {
      services.Remove(descriptor);
    }
    
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(builder =>
    {
      builder.UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase());
    });
  });
```

But because I moved from Npgsql to SQLite in tests I need to override some default values in OnModelCreating. I created a new db context class

```
public class MySqlLiteDbContext: MyDbContext
    {
        public MySqlLiteDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .Property(b => b.DateCreated)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(datetime('now'))");

            ...
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to inject `MySqlLiteDbContext` instead of `MyDbContext` to force EnsureCreated use `OnModelCreating` for SQLite? Is extracting `IMyDbContext` an option? What else can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, looks like I managed to solve it like this

1. Add non-generic DBContext constructor override, make it `protected`

```
    public class MyDbContext: DbContext {        
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions < MyDbContext > options): base(options) {}
        // new
        protected MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options) {}
        
        // rest context stuff...
    }
```

2. Remove DBContext and DBContextOptions in `WebApplicationFactory` on `ConfigureServices`

```
.ConfigureServices(services => {
    // Remove the app's ApplicationDbContext registration.
    var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof (DbContextOptions < MyDbContext > ));

    if (descriptor != null) {
        services.Remove(descriptor);
    }

    var descriptor2 = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof (MyDbContext));

    if (descriptor2 != null) {
        services.Remove(descriptor2);
    }

    //...
})
```

3. Add your descendant context as implementation

```
.ConfigureServices(services => {
    // Remove the app's ApplicationDbContext registration.

    // ...
    services.AddDbContext < MyDbContext, MySqliteDbContext > (builder => {
        builder.UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase());
    }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
})
```

Note: If you use InMemory Sqlite consider Singleton scope.

4. Done. Now when `DocumentComparisonContext` injected `DocumentComparisonSqlLiteContext` will be used as implementation, and on `EnsureCreated` sqlite-specific logic will be used.

Answer (score 2):

Register DbContext with the Services Container.
Open Startup.cs and in the ConfigureServices function, we are going to use the AddDbContext extension method to add our new DbContext and tell it to use SQLite with the connection string from our appsettings.json. The following is the full function with the first two lines being the ones we added.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ContactsDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddOpenApiDocument(document => 
        document.PostProcess = d => d.Info.Title = "Contacts API");
}
```